# Jquery: drop down menu wont disappear after clicking outside of menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new to jquery and I'm looking at google's code to create their 'More' button. I've got it working atm but the only way to make the drop down disappear is to click the 'More' button again. Is there a method I can add to change this so that any click outside of the drop down menu itself will close it? Thanks for the insight!

http://jsfiddle.net/rKaPN/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bind a click event to html to capture any click made, and make it hide the menu

```
$("html").click(function() {
  menu.find('.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

Then override that on your menu's `click` event using `.stopPropagation();`

```
menu.find('ul li > a').bind('click', function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rKaPN/12/

Comment: not a very good solution because on each click this will do a lot of unnecessary work each time, when the menu is already hidden

Answer (score 1):

You could add this too , so the user don't have to click

```
$("body:not(.menu)").hover(function(){ $(".menu").find('.active').removeClass('active');})
```

Comment: nice I like this a lot too, will def keep this incase I need it down the road

Answer (score 0):

On opening of the menu, create a transparent overlay div of the same width and height of the window. On click of that div, close the menu and destroy the div.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than testing every click on the html dom element you could bind a blur event to the specific menu item when you make it active to then switch it off when the blur event is fired. Replace these few lines:

```
  //displaying the drop down menu
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
```

with these:

```
  //displaying the drop down menu
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  $(this).blur(function() {
      $('.active').removeClass('active');
  });
```