# how to close a dropdown on clicking anywhere on the body using jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, show-hide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery: drop down menu wont disappear after clicking outside of menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921802/jquery-drop-down-menu-wont-disappear-after-clicking-outside-of-menu)

I recently found a tutorial on [creating google like black menu bar with the dropdown](http://blog.geotitles.com/2011/09/creating-the-new-top-black-bar-found-in-google-and-all-its-products/)

the dropdown is displayed when we click on the 'more' button, to hide the dropdown again we should click on the 'more' button again

but i want to close the dropdown by clicking anywhere on the body, can anyone let me know how

http://jsfiddle.net/VrmnA/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look here :
jquery-drop-down-menu-wont-disappear-after-clicking-outside-of-menu

Comment: This has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7921802/1015208), still here is the solution http://jsfiddle.net/FNPY4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic logic should be like this : if clicked anywhere outside the menu, close the dropdown :

```
var dropdown = $('dropdown_selector');
$(document).click(function(e){
    if(e.target === dropdown.get(0))
        {
            // hide dropdawn code here
        }
});
```

Here's a live demo :

#### http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/VrmnA/7/

P.S. :  the demo is working for the latest jquery version

Answer (score 1):

If you give the div holding the main content an id (in the example below i've added an id of 'content' to this div) then you could close any active menus from there when it is clicked on:

```
$('#content').click(function() {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

Alternatively bind a blur event to remove the active class when it is added:

```
  //hiding drop down menu when it is clicked again
  if ($(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
  }
  else {
    //displaying the drop down menu
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    $(this).blur(function() {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
    });
  }
```

[Updated jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/VrmnA/5/)

Comment: @user1018414 - what exactly isn't working, just tried the jsFiddle link and it seems ok?

Comment: I tried the jsFiddle and when I click anywhere on the body, the dropdown doesn't close

Answer (score 0):

Ironically, this exact same question was asked recently: [Jquery: drop down menu wont disappear after clicking outside of menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921802/jquery-drop-down-menu-wont-disappear-after-clicking-outside-of-menu)

The user explained that you can simply bind a click event to the `html` tag of your markup, which will close the dropdown and how to stop your dropdown from instantly closing if you click on an item in the dropdown using `e.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: yes I just realized that
do you think deleting a duplicate question is a proper practice ?

Comment: Well the question is already closed and different answers were given this time around, which future users could also benefit from.